# servoblaster device file is sometimes too slow

Tags: software-development

I am using [servoblaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster) to control ESC with the Raspberry Pi. I am using the kernel module with default config and write to servoblaster's device file up to 50 times per second. I am using c and the POSIX functions to open and write to servoblaster's device file. It usually takes 0.6 milliseconds to write, but sometimes, for a few seconds, the writes take up to 10 milliseconds. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using servoblaster's user space implementation which seems to be more stable than the older kernel driver.

Answer (score 0):

> It usually takes 0.6 milliseconds to write, but sometimes, for a few seconds, the writes take up to 10 milliseconds. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

It is a multi-tasking system, and a bit of latency is possible.  You could try upping the priority of the process (see `man nice`), and trying to keep the system as inactive as possible otherwise.

The latency may be slipping in where you are coming in and out of system calls.  E.g.:

```
while (1) {
    write(...);
    // do some calculations in userspace
}
```

I'm presuming you are just trying to do this as fast as possible, and you aren't using any kind of (passive) delay.  **If so, *don't do this with a granularity finer than 10 ms* because you will not get predictable results otherwise.**  The issue is that during the sleep the scheduler may run something else, and a normal kernel can't prevent that from taking <= 10 ms (as in, it *may* be less, but it won't be more).<sup>1</sup>

If you are not using a delay, try combining your writes together.  Userspace <-> kernel space context switches are expensive.

<sup>1</sup> That's a number I've seen repeated but can't find any current references to. If you do some tests with timing timers (e.g., by using `gettimeofday()` to check how much time has actually passed), you'll probably notice pauses with a granularity of 10 ms are accurate to the millsecond, but finer ones aren't.  I.e., a sleep of 10 ms will be 10 ms, but a sleep of 5 ms may be 7 or 9, etc.

Busy looping (e.g., by just polling `gettimeofday()`) might improve upon that, but it means your program will max the processor, which makes it kind of infeasible for most things.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But does this explain the huge (!) time difference between 0.6ms and 10ms for a write? Most of the time, it goes well, and suddenly, writes take 10ms and get gradual faster, like a jam which gets resolved.I tested the same code with the difference that I write to a normal file instead of the device file. Writes took 1ms, but the write time was stable. Also, I set the thread priority to SCHED_FIFO via POSIX functions, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't really explain it.  If it persists no matter what you do with priorities and optimizing the writes, I'd presume it is a delay from somewhere low down -- either the driver for the device is glitchy, or the device itself (or the pi / the interface on the pi).